# Javascript Modal popup between themes on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, modal-dialog, themes, gravityforms

I have an issue with a javascript modal not working between 2 themes on a Wordpress site.

I have a form that has a modal popup with a subform that allows you to submit multiple items to a list.

Here is a copy of the working example form. This is Wordpress theme Twenty Sixteen.
http://www.taftcollege.edu/web-tasks/nested-forms-test/

Pressing "Add Salad" appropriately shows the modal.

Here is the not working version on our custom theme. 
http://www.taftcollege.edu/safety/modal-test/

Clicking "Add Salad" works in the first version of the form and not in the second. 
There is a modal button at the bottom of the forms that works on both forms.

As far as I can tell there's no reason it shouldn't be working. But try as I might I am unable to diagnose the specific reason that it's not working. There's no error showing up in the console.

The author of the theme is unreachable and the author of Gravity Perks has refused to help me with this issue.

Comment: You need to add more information, such as errors you are getting in the console, etc.

Comment: As I said in the post, there are no errors produced in the console. Notices yes, but both the working and none working version produce those.

Comment: I see both modals: https://imgur.com/a/FDcZlL6

Comment: That's a proof of concept that the pagebuilder modals work. Click "Add Salad" on each form to see the issue.

Comment: Sorry should have been more precise in the OP.